# How to create a FIFO queue to a cell array of cell arrays in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, queue, fifo, cell-array

Let's say that we have a cell array of cell arrays, called Q, a <1x3256 cell>, and each cell is a cell array like this one below, for example:

> > Q{1}{1}

ans =

```
 0   451     0
```

etc. The problem is, that i want to create a FIFO queue in order to "clear" every cell and send the contents of each cell to another function (in the above cell the values 0 451 0), one by one each time. It is essential to use a FIFO queue and only, because it is a part of an implementation of a specific algorithm. 
If possible, i would rather not to use Java in Matlab, like LinkedList, as i have already read in other topics.

How could i do that FIFO queue with this cell array of cell arrays?Any ideas? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the first value

```
input = Q(1);  % or Q{1} depending on requirements
```

Clear the first value:

```
Q(1) = []; % Q will now be, e.g. 1x3255 cell
% Q(1) is now the old Q(2)
```

This needs to be () not {} - the latter will empty the contents of `Q(1)` only (`Q` will remain 1 x 3256).

To add additional values to the end of the queue:

```
Q(end+1) = newdata;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, you've got some very good approach on the issue here. I'd like to ask you two things: First, could this solution be more FIFO-like? Meaning, by using both head and tail variables for the first and last element of the queue Q respectively? And also, could you please give me a hand on how to actually add the newdata to the end of the queue? I think it's much more complicated than this general statement  Q(end+1) = newdata;  because we have to deal with a cell array of cell arrays. Thanks in advance!